# Retornar ID de usuário facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Como eu consigo atraves de um campo input informando meu username do facebook, retornar o meu número (id) de usuário do Facebook?

Caso

Input: http://www.facebook.com/usuario

Output: $profile= '4559875758';echo $profile;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende, se estiver usando a API oficial do Facebook (*devido a uso da tag facebook-graph-api*) não há como. Desde a versão 2.1 da API, salvo engano, os identificadores são individuais, sendo assim cada usuário (e cada aplicativo) possui um *id* diferente para um mesmo usuário.

---

Entretanto, se não está usando a API Oficial, então pode simplesmente fazer uma requisição para `https://facebook.com.br/seu_nome` e obter o `id`, para isso você pode utilizar o *poderoso* cURL.

Para obter o `id` basta obter o valor do `entity_id` que está presente na página do perfil, no código HTML. Para essa finalidade usamos o REGEX (`/"entity_id":([0-9]+)/`) para simplificar a coisa:

```
function getFacebookIdentifier($ProfileContent_result){

    if(preg_match('/"entity_id":([0-9]+)/', $ProfileContent_result, $matches)){
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return false;

}
```

Isto irá retornar `false` caso não seja possível encontrar.

Para obter o conteúdo do perfil, a página, iremos utilizar o CURL, entretanto basicamente precisamos de duas coisas:

- **URL** para se conectar (`https://m.facebook.com/nome_de_usuario`).
- **User-Agent** para se passar por um navegador comum (Neste caso *BlackBerry 10*, afinal estamos se conectando com o `https://m.`)

No final terá isto:

```
function getFacebookProfileContent($name){

    return sendRequest('https://m.facebook.com/'.$name, [
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Kbd) AppleWebKit/537.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.0.4633 Mobile Safari/537.10+'
    ]);

}
```

Agora apenas criamos a função `sendRequest`, que será encarregada de fazer a chamada usando o CURL:

```
function sendRequest($url, $headers = []){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    ]);

    return curl_exec($ch);

}
```

> **/!\** Esse cURL possui uma série de problemas de segurança, esteja ciente disto!

---

Dessa forma basta utilizar:

```
$nome = 'inkeliz';

if($id = getFacebookIdentifier( getFacebookProfileContent($nome) )){

    echo $id;

}
```

---

Uma solução para o bloqueio de ["não ser encontrado pelo sistema de busca"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199114/retornar-id-de-usu%C3%A1rio-facebook#comment409251_199128) é especificar os *cookies* de uma conta do Facebook já conectada, assim o Facebook irá obter o perfil porque está conectado no Facebook (e não um visitante).

Se você tiver uma conta no Facebook, conecte nela e então copie os *cookies* e então defina usando:

```
    sendRequest('https://m.facebook.com/'.$name, [
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Kbd) AppleWebKit/537.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.0.4633 Mobile Safari/537.10+',
        'cookie: '.$_SEU_COOKIE_AQUI
    ]);
```

Para obter o *cookie* de uma conta conectada, basta interceptar/monitorar a conexão, a sua própria é fácil. Entre no Facebook (logado em uma conta) e depois abra o Console > Network procure por uma requisição feita para o `facebook.com` e em `Request Headers` copie tudo que estiver em `cookie:` (sim, é bem longo). Desta forma poderá obter as informações.

Comment: Qual erro apresentado? Existe algo nos logs? Você possui o cURL habilitado? Isto é PHP, ele deve ser processado em seu servidor, portanto não importa se está num iframe ou fora dele. Para manipular um `iframe` ambos devem estar no mesmo domínio.

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste, com o mesmo código (https://pastebin.com/nnZRGzVi) usando XAMPP (com PHP 7.1) e o resultado foi o `id` do usuário, normalmente.

Comment: O curioso é que para alguns profiles funciona, para outros ele nao traz o valor. Tente para davi.reimannrossini

Comment: Retornou normalmente, 749748573, [que está correto](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=749748573).

Comment: Isto é uma configuração de sua conta do Facebook, em https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy&section=search&view, habilite para que o seu perfil seja visível para quem não possui conta. Existe uma solução para isto, irei acrescentar essa informação. Experimente acessar este URL através do navegador anonimo, sem login com o Facebook, isso é o mesmo que o cURL obtem, que não é o seu perfil. ;)

Comment: Agora fez sentido o porque não aparecia. Mas e se for um usuário que não seja eu logado? Eu teria que capturar/interceptar  o cookie e chamar ele na variavel. Correto?